# Creating while connectOrCreate relationships in Prisma

Tags: mysql, typescript, next.js, prisma, planetscale

I am getting some type errors in my Next.JS work using typescript and prisma.

This is the relevant information regarding my case.

```
model Game {
  id              Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  upvote_count    Int       @default(0)
  title           String
  studio          String?
  thumbnail       String?
  blockchain      String?
  description     String?
  tagline         String?
  isTeam          Boolean   @default(true)
  fundraising     String?
  links           String?
  genres          Genre[]   @relation("GameGenre")
  gallery         String?
  stage           DevStatus?  
  ownerId         Int?
  owner           Users?    @relation(fields:[ownerId], references: [id])
  createdAt       DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime  @updatedAt
  @@unique([title, studio], name:"title_studio")
}

model Genre {
  genre       String  @id @unique
  description String?
  games       Game[]  @relation("GameGenre")
}

enum DevStatus {
  preProduction
  production
  playableDemo
  live
}
```

so the npx prisma generate runs fine but I get type errors thrown in my seed.ts file

```
interface Genres {
  genre: string;
  description?: string;
}

interface Genre {
  where: { name: Genres };
  create: { name: Genres };
}

enum DevStatus {
  preProduction = "preProduction",
  production = "production",
  playableDemo = "playableDemo",
  live = "live",
}

interface Game {
  title: string;
  studio: string;
  thumbnail?: string;
  blockchain?: string;
  description?: string;
  tagline?: string;
  isTeam?: boolean;
  fundraising?: string;
  links?: string;
  genres?: Genre | string[];
  gallery?: string;
  stage?: string;
}


async function seedGames() {
  const games: Game[] = DATA;
  for (const row of games) {
    const existingRow = await prisma.game.findUnique({
      where: {
        title_studio: {
          title: row.title,
          studio: row.studio,
        },
      },
    });
    if (!existingRow) {
      //genreData = ["genre", "genre"]

      //{ where: { name: "RPG" }, create: { name: "RPG" } }
      try {
        const gameGenres = row.genres;
        const genresData = connectOrCreateFieldsFromArrayOfStrings(gameGenres);
        const resp = await prisma.game.create({
          data: {
            title: row.title,
            studio: row.studio,
            thumbnail: row.thumbnail,
            description: row.description,
            blockchain: row.blockchain,
            tagline: row.tagline,
            isTeam: row.isTeam,
            fundraising: row.fundraising,
            links: row.links,
            gallery: row.gallery,
            stage: row.stage,
            genres: {
              connectOrCreate: genresData,
            },
          },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("caught error while creating a game in db", error);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(
        `Skipping creation of ${row.title} and ${row.studio}, already exists in database.`
      );
    }
  }
  prisma.$disconnect();
}
```

if anyone has any advice please let me know!

I was trying to run seed.ts but I get these error messages

```
prisma/seed.ts:107:15 - error TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable<GenreCreateOrConnectWithoutGamesInput> | undefined'.

107               connectOrCreate: genresData,
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prisma/seed.ts:113:13 - error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DevStatus | null | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DevStatus | null | undefined'.

113             stage: row.stage,
                ~~~~~

  node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:5455:5
    5455     stage?: DevStatus | null
             ~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'stage' which is declared here on type '(Without<GameCreateInput, GameUncheckedCreateInput> & GameUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & GameCreateInput)'
prisma/seed.ts:128:50 - error TS7006: Parameter 'arrOfStrings' implicitly has an 'any' type.

128 function connectOrCreateFieldsFromArrayOfStrings(arrOfStrings): object {
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
prisma/seed.ts:129:28 - error TS7006: Parameter 'genre' implicitly has an 'any' type.

129   return arrOfStrings.map((genre) => ({
                               ~~~~~

    at createTSError (/Users/andrewchoi/Desktop/workspace/thecoreloop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/andrewchoi/Desktop/workspace/thecoreloop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/andrewchoi/Desktop/workspace/thecoreloop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/Users/andrewchoi/Desktop/workspace/thecoreloop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/andrewchoi/Desktop/workspace/thecoreloop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/andrewchoi/Desktop/workspace/thecoreloop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2322, 2322, 7006, 7006 ]
}
```